# How do i add heading level tags in structure tree for pdf?

Tags: java, itext, accessibility

I am using the below code to add heading level tags for the screen reader to read:

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph("A guide to key terms").setFontSize(18).setBold();
para.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.H1);    
document.add(para);
```

But I am getting the following error:

> incompatible types : Paragraph cannot be converted to element.

Comment: Can you just check what is .setBold() method is returning.

Comment: it is just to display the text in bold..i don't think it's creating any issue.

Comment: I asked the return type of setBold() method

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add heading level tags by setting the role in chunk and then adding it to paragraph.

```
Chunk heading = new Chunk("A guide to key terms\n " , font);
heading.setRole(PdfName.H1);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Chunk(heading));
document.add(paragraph);
```